# Table not flushing left as expected

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to make my tables flush left and overall align with the text.  Using `to \textwidth` manages to make the table the right size, but it won't align properly with the text sometimes. It is slightly indented, which makes it overhang the margins on the right as well as the undesired behavior seen in my example below.

Here is my MNWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable,tabu}

\newcommand{\TableSetupFourColumns}{
\rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {lccX}
    \rowcolor{gray!50}}

\begin{document}

\section{Test 1}
This is the text I want the table to align with after flushing.\par \noindent
\TableSetupFourColumns
    Test            & test  & test  & test\\
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have a trailing space in your definition. Use

```
\newcommand{\TableSetupFourColumns}{%  <----
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  I can't upvote you until I get another 4 reputation unfortunately, but that's exactly what I needed.  Could someone else do me the favor?

Comment: @LearningLaTeX - There, I've just given your question the needed upvote. Incidentally, for every "accept" you'll get another 2 points. :-)